# Using argument as a part of "for each"

Tags: javascript, function

I try to create a simple script that will take RGB-16 colors and convert them to RGB-8. The script works, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to convert it to function so that it will work for two different palettes. Using `palette.forEach` causes an error. The problem seems to be easy to understand, but I cannot spot it out.

```js
const system41 = [
  [65535, 65535, 65535],
  [64512, 62333,  1327],
  [65535, 25738,   652]
];

const system7 = [
  [65535, 65535, 52428],
  [65535, 52428, 39321],
  [52428, 39321, 26214]
];

function convert(palette) {
    palette.forEach((child) => {
        const rgb8 = child.map(value => Math.round(value / 257));
        document.querySelector('#' + palette).innerHTML += rgb8.join(', ') + '\n';
    });
}

convert('system41');
convert('system7');
```

```html
<p>System 4.1 system colors</p>
<pre id="system41"></pre>

<p>System 7 icon colors</p>
<pre id="system7"></pre>
```

Comment: You are passing **strings** to your function, not references to the arrays.

Comment: Also you are almost certainly getting errors reported in your browser console; why are you not checking that?

Comment: Well, now I understand, thanks. So it seems I need to find a way to convert strings to array references...

Comment: No, you don't need a way to convert them. Just don't put quotes around the names of the arrays.

Comment: @Pointy Not quite, `document.querySelector('#' + palette)`.

Comment: Pointy, I checked the console, of course. And despite of the new account, I'm here at SO for about 10+ years (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5587480/john-c-j) Error messages on Safari are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your arrays in an object so you can perform string-wise lookups.

```js
const palettes = {
  system41: [
    [65535, 65535, 65535],
    [64512, 62333, 1327],
    [65535, 25738, 652]
  ],
  system7: [
    [65535, 65535, 52428],
    [65535, 52428, 39321],
    [52428, 39321, 26214]
  ]
};

function convert(palette) {
  palettes[palette].forEach((child) => {
    const rgb8 = child.map(value => Math.round(value / 257));
    document.querySelector('#' + palette).innerHTML += rgb8.join(', ') + '\n';
  });
}

convert('system41');
convert('system7');
```

```html
<p>System 4.1 system colors</p>
<pre id="system41"></pre>

<p>System 7 icon colors</p>
<pre id="system7"></pre>
```